# Gnome do installation and disk space usage

Tags: disk-usage, gnome-do

I installed Gnome-Do on Xubuntu and it said 52 MB of disk space will be used up while installation. Later when i removed it (I used `purge`), only 7 MB was freed. Each time I install some applet, am I losing disk spac?

Comment: what are orphan packages? This surely won't remove any necessary stuff right ?

Answer (score 1):

Many other packages are automatically installed when you install a package to satisfy dependencies.

After removing that package, you need to remove these orphan package

Use can use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove those unnecessary orphan packages